# Calling different Object's Constructor on each index of Array/Collection

Tags: java, arrays, collections, foreach, constructor

I'm trying to tidy up my code as I have many different classes that need to be initialized before my program is ready to do it's tasks.
They are all optional and can fail, but one of them has to succeed.
All these classes implement an interface called Hook.

Each initialization is put into a HashMap, here is an example:

```
HashMap<String, Hook> hooks = new HashMap<>();
String key = "Fish";
if (isEnabled(key)) {
 try {
  hooks.put(key, new FishStoreHook());
 } catch {
  logError(key);
 }
}
```

But now I have to have another one for, say Bread:

```
key = "Bread";
if (isEnabled(key)) {
 try {
  hooks.put(key, new BreadStoreHook());
 } catch {
  logError(key);
 }
}
```

Is there a way to put something in an array or Collection so that they can be called with a for each statement?

(Reason they are put into a HashMap is because their methods are run with a for each HashMap.keySet(), and I need to log possible errors)
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using reflection:

```
String className = "package.name." + key  + "StoreHook";
Class<Hook> clazz = (Class<Hook>) YourClass.class.forName(className);
Hook hook = clazz.newInstance();
```

OR If you are using Spring, you can also get all sub types of `Hook`.

```
ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider provider = new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
provider.addIncludeFilter(new AssignableTypeFilter(Hook.class));
Set<BeanDefinition> definitions = provider.findCandidateComponents("package/name");

Map<String, Hook> hooks = new HashMap<>();
for (BeanDefinition definition : definitions) {
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName(definition.getBeanClassName());
        hooks.put(clazz.getSimpleName(), clazz.newInstance());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        logger.error("Unable to get class: ", e);
    }
}
```

And then you can get your instance from hashmap.

Comment: Reflection worked perfectly, Thank you so much! :)  
Reduced code from 150 lines to 17, absolutely fantastic.  
  
Although my constructor had arguments in it I managed to get that to run with
`clazz.getConstructor(Plan.class).newInstance(this)`

Answer (score 0):

You can add all `Hook` objects to a `List` and then use a `for-each` as shown in the below code with inline comments:

```
List<Hook> hooks = new ArrayList<>();
hooks.add(new FishStoreHook("Fish"));//Pass HookName as a constructor arg
hooks.add(new BreadStoreHook("Bread"));//Pass HookName as a constructor arg
//add other hook objects

//Now iterate all the hook objects using foreach
for(Hook hook : hooks) {
  if(isEnabled(hook.getName())) {//get HookName (set through constrcutor above)
     try {
          hooks.put(key, hook);
         } catch {
              logError(key);
            }
        }
     }
```

Comment: Ah Thanks for the reply. Maybe I wasn't very clear, but when I call the constructor it tries to use methods from another .jar that is an optional library - in case the library doesn't exist, when run the constructor throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    @SuppressWarnings( "serial" )
    final Map<String, Callable<Hook>> init =
        new LinkedHashMap<String, Callable<Hook>>() {{
            put( "Fish", new Callable<Hook>() {
                @Override public Hook call() throws Exception {
                    return new FishStoreHook(); }} );
            put( "Bread", new Callable<Hook>() {
                @Override public Hook call() throws Exception {
                    return new BreadStoreHook(); }} );
        }};

    final Map<String, Hook> hooks = new HashMap<>();
    for( Map.Entry<String, Callable<Hook>> e: init.entrySet() )
        try {
            if( isEnabled( e.getKey() ) )
                hooks.put( e.getKey(), e.getValue().call() );
        } catch( Exception ex ) {
            logError( e.getKey() );
        }
```

You need the `LinkedHashMap` in case you care about the order, otherwise just any kind of `Map` would do.